# Spring, how to broadcast message to connected clients using websockets?

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I am trying to use websockets in my app. I have followed this tutorial:
   http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

It works perfectly.

When one of connected clients press button, this method is called:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Sending message...");
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("hello!");        
}
```

and message is broadcasted to all of connected clients.

Now i want to modify my server app, that it will broadcast messages periodically (each hour) to all of my connected clients, without interaction from clients.

Something like this(but this is not working obviously):

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
public void sendMessage(){
   try {
   @SendTo("/topic/greetings")     
   greeting();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Thx for advices.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@SendTo` works only in the `SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler`, which is initiated only through the `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler`, hance when the `WebSocketMessage` is received from clients.

To achieve your requirements you should inject to the your `@Scheduled` service `SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate` and use it directly:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate;
.......
this.brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "foo");
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? how do I inject it?

Comment: Please see an edit in my answer around `@Autowired`.